# How to compile a a project that use tokio::signal::unix on Windows?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

How to compile a project that's using tokio::signal::unix on Windows?
Whenever I try to compile a project with tokio::signal::unix, it will show this error.

```
58 | use tokio::signal::unix::SignalKind;
   |                    ^^^^ could not find `unix` in `signal`
```

Or is there a better way to handle signal with no regard to the operating system?

Is there's any way to make the code base useable regardless of the platform?

Comment: What signals do you want to handle? Obviously signals that only exist on Unix platforms aren't available on Windows. The only signal can be gotten from Tokio in a cross-platform way is `tokio::signal::ctrl_c`.

Comment: @kmdreko So, any way to make it compilable on Windows or a way to make tokio useable regardless of the platform?

Comment: Fix the project to not use Unix-specific features when compiling on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS signal are specific to each operating system, so you cannot use Unix signals on Windows. The only cross platform signal `tokio` supports is ctrl-c but if you want to support both platforms then you can use `cfg` to select the platform specific import

```rust
#[cfg(unix)]
use tokio::signal::unix;
#[cfg(windows)]
use tokio::signal::windows;
```

and then in your code, use the library for that platform

```rust
#[cfg(unix)]
println!("On Unix"); // Only runs on Unix/Linux
#[cfg(windows)]
println!("On Windows"); // Only runs on Windows
```

All the Unix specific signals can be found [here](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/signal/unix/struct.SignalKind.html#implementations) and the Windows specific [here](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/signal/windows/index.html)